# Date subtraction in bash

Tags: bash, date

I want to get successive differences of dates shown sample below. How do I convert each of these dates into epoch seconds?

```
7/21/17 6:39:12:167 GMT
7/21/17 6:39:12:168 GMT
7/21/17 6:39:12:168 GMT
7/21/17 6:39:12:205 GMT
7/21/17 6:39:12:206 GMT
7/21/17 6:39:12:206 GMT
```

Once each line gets converted into epoch seconds, I can simply run another script to get successive differentials of each. Thanks.

Comment: What is `6:39:12:167`?

Comment: What is the thing after the last colon?

Comment: post how should look the expected result

Comment: Sorry for not fully describing what each field means in the time stamps. I was looking how SystemOut.log in Websphere formats the timestamp but i could not find quickly what the rightmost means either it is milliseconds is my best guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one in GNU awk. It converts the timestamps to epoch time in seconds and subtracts the former from the latter. `mktime` function used for converting doesn't take fraction of a seconds but the fractions are stored to hash `a[7]` and nothing stops you from adding it to `t` var before subtracting:

```
$ awk '
function zeropad(s) {              # zeropad function 
    return sprintf("%02d", s)
}
{
    split($0,a,"[/ :]")            # split timestamp to a
    for(i in a) 
        a[i]=zeropad(a[i])         # zeropad all components
    t=mktime(20 a[3] " " a[1] " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6]) 
    # add the fractions in a[7] here
    if(NR>1)                       # might be unnecessary
        print t-p                  # output subtracted seconds
    p=t                            # set current time to previous
}' file
0
0
0
0
0
```

Since you didn't include the expected output or proper data sample, that's the best I can do for now.

**EDIT:**

Since your data does not fully reflect if the fraction of a second are presented like 0:0:0:100 or 0:0:0:1 I modified the `zeropad` function to left and right pad given values. Now you call it like `zeropad(value, count, left/right)` or `zeropad(a[7],3,"r")`:

```
function zeropad(s,c,d) {
    return sprintf("%" (d=="l"? "0" c:"") "d" (d=="r"?"%0" c-length(s) "d":""), s,"")
}
{
    split($0,a,"[/ :]")            # split timestamp to a
    for(i in a) 
        a[i]=zeropad(a[i],2,"l")   # left-pad all components with 0s
    t=mktime(20 a[3] " " a[1] " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6]) 
    t=t+zeropad(a[7],3,"r")/1000   # right-pad fractions with 0s
    if(NR>1)                       # might be unnecessary
        print t-p                  # output subtracted seconds
    p=t                            # set current time to previous
}
0.00999999
0
0.37
0.00999999
0
```

`printf` with proper modifiers should probably be used for outputing to get sane values.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert times using the [`date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command.  Given a line like this:

```
7/21/17 6:39:12:167 GMT
```

You first need to strip everything at and after the seconds part, to get this:

```
7/21/17 6:39:12
```

You can use `cut -d: -f1-3` for that.  Then, convert to epoch seconds, if you're using FreeBSD or Mac OS:

```
date -ujf "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S" "7/21/17 6:39:12" +%s
```

Which gives:

```
1500619152
```

If you are using GNU date (e.g. on Linux), you can feed an entire file of dates to it.  Since the input file isn't in the right format, we can do this:

```
date --file <(cut -d: -f1-3 infile) +%s
```

That will read the entire file with only a single invocation of `date`, which is much more efficient, but only works with GNU date.

Comment: Which system, what version of 'date' you are using there is no such -j flag in my cygwin nor in my redhat

Comment: @daixtr: I see you're using GNU systems then.  I've updated my answer with a more efficient way to do it with GNU date.  My original solution used the BSD-style date command.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have one of those dates in a variable:

```
$ d='7/21/17 6:39:12:167 GMT'
```

With GNU date, we need to remove the milliseconds part.  That can be done with bash's *pattern substitution*:

```
$ echo "${d/:??? / }"
7/21/17 6:39:12 GMT
```

To convert that to seconds-since-epoch, we use the `-d` option to set the date and the `%s` format to request seconds-since-epoch:

```
$ date -d "${d/:??? / }" +%s
1500619152
```

*Compatibility*: Mac OSX does not support GNU's `-d` option but I gather it has similar option.  On many operating systems, including OSX, there is the option to install GNU utilities.